# Chromecast limited to 720p images?

Tags: chromecast

According to their docs Chromecast only supports 1080x720 images, which I think does not apply to the New Chromecast that supports 1080p. As a person who closely follows documentation I am unsure if I am using the wrong one (for the old chromecast), a outdated one or if this still applies to the new chromecast?

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Comment: I'm confused by this too. The ChromeCast Ultra supports 4k video, but somehow it still only supports 720p images, and no mention of any way to do HDR images. I'm guessing there isn't a big use case for it, but I'd love to simply have a way to display HDR images on a second screen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, receiver apps will see 720p for images but please make sure your app is responsive and doing the right sizing so that if this changes in future, your app can adjust automatically.